# Iterating json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

after looking through a lot of similar questions on SO, I still can't iterate my json structure. How can I reach the value (key) of my inner array?

```
var data = {"User1":{"Service1":2,"Service2":1},"User2":{"Service3":1}}
            
for(var user in data) {
    document.write(user + ': ')
             
    for(var service in data[user]){
        document.write(service + ': ' + user[service])
    }
    document.write("<br />")
}
```

This prints:

> User1: Service1: undefined Service2: undefined
>
> User2: Service3: undefined

And I'd like it to print

> User1: Service1: 2 Service2: 1
>
> User2: Service3: 1

Is javascript enough or do I need jQuery?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no "inner array", there are nested objects though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var data = {
  User1: {
    Service1: 2,
    Service2: 1
  },
  User2: {
    Service3: 1
  }
};
for (var user in data) {
  console.log("User: " + user);
  for (var service in data[user]) {
    console.log("\tService: " + service + "; value: " + data[user][service]);
  }
}
```

Replace `console.log` with `document.write` or whatever.

Comment: Could have sworn I tried that but I must've written data[user[service]]. Silly me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`document.write(service + ': ' + data[user][service])`